# Cannot catch alert modal using Java Selenium WebDriver 4

Tags: java, automated-tests, selenium4

I'm automating this site as a practice https://www.demoblaze.com/index.html, after completing sign up modal and click Sign Up button, another pop up is raised to confirm the sign up process.

If I don't catch the alert modal I get "org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Sign up successful.}"

but if I handle the alert like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        try {
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) {
            System.out.println("no hay alerta");
        }
```

I get "org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert" When I debugged the test, it skips the try/catch sentence.

I also see that I cannot inspect with Chrome browser dev tools or Xpath Helper.

Comment: Try introducing a ` webdriverwait` instead of `implicitlywait`. Now, I am a python guy and I wrote the code in python and it worked for me. I used `Thread.sleep` of 3 seconds. If inducing `sleep` also does not work, then please show your full code to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the Alert using webDriver wait like below and then switch to it

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(60)).ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
```

Comment: .ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class) was the solution I tried and it worked just wonderful, thank you all for taking the time to help me on this.  Really appreciate it